# Entity framework Not Found after updating to Visual Studio 2013 update 4

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2013

Four days ago I updated VS2013.3 to VS2013.4 and entity framework broke.

The error occurs immediately after compeleting the EF dialogue and adding
a table. The diagram displays and I get the error output:

> Metadata file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\NuGet Packages..\IDE\EntityFramework.dll' could not be found   d:\users\allen\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\WebApplication8\WebApplication8\Models\Model1.tt   1   1   WebApplication8

There is NO SUCH FOLDER on my C drive, which is a smallish SSD. I install everything I can on D. I've played with registry setting and system environment variables for VS120COMNTOOLS and nothing seems to work.

I've uninstalled and reinstalled EF, and VS2013.
I'd appreciate any assistance.
Thanks

Comment: Did you try to install the 6,1,3 EF Tools?

Comment: I don't know why it would point to VS11, that's VS2012.  You need to reinstall EF from NuGet.

Comment: Try to repair Visual Studio. If this doesn't work, re-install visual studio.

Comment: Thanks to all, but I have uninstalled/and reinstalled EFTools, VS2013 and NuGet packages. Doesn't seem to make a difference. I DO have VS2012 installed and have NO issues with EF.

Comment: Wait, EFTools?  There's your problem.  EFTools are built into EF6.x, EFTools are only for earlier versions.

Comment: Eric - Thx. See this: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40762